# How to hide server descriptions in Swagger UI?

Tags: yaml, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor, oas

I have an OpenAPI 3.0 definition with multiple servers:

```yaml
servers:
- url: https://development.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Development server
- url: https://staging.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Staging server
- url: https://api.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Production server
```

When this definition is rendered in Swagger UI, the "Servers" dropdown shows the description of each server:

[image: Server descriptions in Swagger UI]

Is it possible to hide the server descriptions from this dropdown?

Comment: Hi @anshulgoel, I edited your question to make it more clear. Let me know if this is not what you meant.

Comment: @Helen I meant the same only with the non editable YAML. Thanks for providing more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger UI always displays the server `description` if it's provided, this is hard-coded:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/oas3/components/servers.jsx#L125

As a workaround you can modify the API definition dynamically after it's loaded and remove server descriptions. To do that, edit your Swagger UI's `swagger-initializer.js` or `index.html` file and add the following `onComplete` function to the `SwaggerUIBundle` initialization code:

```js
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "https://path/to/your/openapi.json",
    ...

    onComplete: function() {
      let spec = ui.specSelectors.specJson().toJS();
      let servers = spec.servers || [];

      for (let i in servers) {
        servers[i].description = ""
      }

      ui.specActions.updateJsonSpec(spec);
    }
  })
```

Comment: We can also consider 3.18 version of swagger. This also worked out for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They haven't provided any option to replace this server's `description` in another place, but they have mentioned the `description` is optional in swagger specification of [object representing a Server](https://swagger.io/specification/#oas-servers).

Swagger UI have not provided any rendering option for this.

The best use of `description` is define in a single word, like *production*, *development*, *api*, *staging*, etc..

If you really don't want in dropdown then you can remove it from your server list.

```yaml
servers:
- url: https://development.gigantic-server.com/v1
- url: https://staging.gigantic-server.com/v1
- url: https://api.gigantic-server.com/v1
```

---

> #### This part i am writing for your information, about how to use **`oas-servers`**,

I observed your server urls, these can be easily define in single url, how? using [server variables](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/).

```yaml
servers:
- url: https://{environment}.gigantic-server.com/{version}
  variables: 
    environment:
      enum:
        - 'development'
        - 'staging'
        - 'api'
    version:
      enum:
        - 'v1'
```

Hope this help.

Comment: No this is not the case, I can't change the YAML file. For me the description is coming, I need to remove that from swagger-ui.

Comment: Have you tried from swagger ui? can you add swagger ui configuration in your question.